# Calculate with variable content in PHP

Tags: php, database

I have a database with products inside. The columns are: `ID`, `prodname`, `calculate`. The `calculate` cells are containing stuff like `($width*$height)`, `(($width+$height)*2)`, `($width*2)`, and so on.

My PHP script contains the same variables with values like `$width = 100`, `$height = 200`.

My problem is that I can not calculate with them. If I read the calculation part from the database and display them like `echo ($row['calculate'])`; the browser gives an output like `$width*$height)`. I would like to have the browser display `(20000)`.

I have no idea what I could do to get the browser work like that. Has someone an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a column in your database containing a string "($width*$height)"? And you want to use that for making calculations?

Comment: I would rethink your approach here. You could use `eval` to evaluate the code you store in the database, but relying heavily on `eval` is a bad idea outside of a small set of use cases. Storing PHP code in your database so you can `eval` it in your application is not a good idea in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string containing PHP code you can use `eval()` to evaluate it. Be aware that it is a big, gaping security hole if there is even the remotest possibility that someone else could influence the data in that string.

```
$str = '$width*$height';
$width = 10;
$height = 20;
$area = eval($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three possibilities:

- Use `eval()` as in @PeterBowers' answer: Not recommended by me
- Replace your variables, then use `eval()`: Better, but still not recommended
- rethink your `calculate` column: If the examples given are representative, you use a fairly small library of calculations - you basically could do something like

.

```
$functions=array(
  '($width*$height)' => function($w, $h) { return $w*$h; },
  '(($width+$height)*2)' => function($w, $h) { return ($w+$h)*2; },
  // ...
);
```

and then

```
$calc=$functions[$row['calculate']]($width, $height);
```

Ofcourse you need to adapt your parameters, check for function existance etc. 
Going forward, you could use named functions and start storing the names of the functions in the `calculate` field, making the job really sane.

Comment: Maybe you can help me a second time…
I used the function, but now my foreach-loop doesn't work anymore. Do you know how to fix that problem?